# How can I set custom ringtone for a single contact?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, aquaris, bq

I want to set different ringtones for the most frequent callers, so I can identify the caller just by hearing how my phone rings.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this right now. But who knows what the future might bring

Comment: If not, why not raise a feature request in Launchpad to get it developed.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Phone app. It's on your phone's home screen, and has a phone icon.
Tap Contacts.
Tap on the contact you want to assign a specific ringtone to.
Tap Edit. It is located in the upper-right corner.
Tap Ringtone.
Tap Add from device storage (optional).
Tap the ringtone you'd like to set,
Tap the back button.

Good luck....